# Redirecting traffic to SOCKS5 tunnel with iptables

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables

I've got a home server (lets call it "A") and I want to access it when I'm outside, not directly though, but through a support machine connected to the same network (lets call it "B").
I figured the best way to do this would be to use B as an SSH socks5 proxy, which would also provide a nice layer of security.

So first I open the tunnel on port 9100 with `ssh -D 9100 USER_B@IP_B`, and that works fine - if i manually enable socks proxy under `localhost:9100` I can then connect to the internal A's address, like 192.168.1.100.

The problem with this approach is that i have to enable every single application to use the proxy manually, and, even worse, I'd prefer to restrict the use of this only for the requests that actually need to reach A.

The problem is I'm a bit of a newbye when it comes to networking. I came across `iptables` and after looking it up I think it can be used to change the source port of tcp packets directed to A's internal address to 9100 hoping the proxy will take care of the rest, so I did `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.100 -j SNAT -p tcp --to-source :9100`, but when i try to connect to a website in A i get no response.

Any help to understand what's going on and what i need to fix is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This won't work: for an application to use your SOCKS proxy, it has to speak the SOCKS protocol. Just redirection packets with iptables isn't going to fix that for you. If instead of a SOCKS proxy you set up a VPN (using e.g. [wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/), [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/), etc), then simple routing rules take care of everything for you (and applications don't require special support).

Comment: I thought that if i change the port of the outgoing message it would go to the SSH application which does the tunnel and it would take care of the protocol, or am I just making stuff up?

Comment: Ssh is providing a SOCKS proxy. Your application needs SOCKS support and it needs to know that it's talking to a SOCKS proxy in order for this to work. There are utilities that will "wrap" an application so that it will work with a SOCKS proxy (look for `tsocks` and `socksify`), but they're a bit hacky.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I don´t like hacky solutions. If I were to use wireguard in my example to connect to B , how would I go about further jumping to A in the internal network at 192.168.xxx?
I´d rather not install anything on A.
Say for instance there is a web server at 192.168.1.100:4100

Comment: Think and try youself